# How can we parametrize a data displayed on Html pages with Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Is there any method that can help to parametrize data which is displayed on html-pages, and which is not entered via forms without using CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

1. [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters)
2. [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)
   [Jmeter UDV User Defined Variable Tips and Help](http://coreplex.blogspot.com/2008/10/jmeter-udv-user-defined-variable-tips.html)

Look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6099307/993246) as well.